# Is this quotient space homeomorphic to a "3-dimensional Möbius strip"?

Tags: general-topology

Consider a closed non-self-intersecting curve $\Gamma$ embedded in $\mathbb R^2$. We can parametrize this curve through a function $\mathbf r : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ such that $\mathbf r[0,1] = \Gamma$ and $\mathbf r(0) = \mathbf r(1)$. Now, if $\mathbf r$ is a sufficiently regular parametrization (bicontinuous, injective, non-singular Jacobian etc.) any point in $\Gamma$ has a unique preimage through $\mathbf r$, besides the point corresponding to $0\equiv 1$.

This means that every *ordered* pair of points in $\Gamma$ corresponds to one and only one point in the unit square $[0,1]^2$ with opposite sides glued together, i.e. the 2-dimensional torus $\mathbb T^2 \simeq \mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1$. For *unordered* pairs, one may fold said square along the diagonal connecting $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ since all points of the form $(x,y)$ become indistinguishable from their "inverted" counterparts of the form $(y,x)$. It can be seen that this new object corresponds to a Möbius strip (see [this beautiful video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmgkSdhK4K8&t=6m59s) for a walkthrough of this whole process)

Now imagine doing this again for *triples* of points in $\Gamma$. We'll need to consider the unit cube $[0,1]^3$ which, through the identification $0 \equiv 1$ on all axes, becomes the 3-dimensional torus $\mathbb T^3 = \mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1$ – and this would correspond to the space of all ordered triples of points on $\Gamma$. Now what becomes of the *unordered* triples, i.e. the space of ordered triples fed through the equivalence relation
$$(x,y,z) \equiv (x',y',z') \quad :\Leftrightarrow \quad (x',y',z') = (\pi(x),\pi(y),\pi(z)), \quad \pi \in S_3$$
Is there a surface contained in the unit cube that would correspond to the "crease" that appears in the case of the unit square? What topological space is the space of unordered triples of points in $\Gamma$ homeomorphic to? (I'm suspecting some sort of 3-dimensional Möbius strip, but can't thoroughly justify this to myself)

Comment: I do not think this space has a name. It is a 3d manifold with boundary, whose boundary is the Klein bottle. One can describe it as a nontrivial bundle over the circle with the fiber Moebius band.